# Creating a list of Bindings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to set one of two `Binding`s on a `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` (based on the selection in a group of `RadioButton`s).

What I have now is:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Binding x:Key="AllBinding" Path="ItemsSource.AllLeaves" ElementName="EmployeeTree" />
        <Binding x:Key="FolderBinding" Path="SelectedItem.Leaves" ElementName="EmployeeTree" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Then ideally I would set one or the other to the `ItemsSource` based on the user's selection.

But I get this error on both `Binding`s:

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Value' property of type 'DictionaryEntry'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

How can I implement this requirement? Is it even possible to define the `Binding`s so I can just swap them in and out from code behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to set your `TreeView.ItemsSource` based on the selected item in some `ListBox`.

If this is the case, you should write a `DataTrigger` on your `EmployeeTree` that sets `TreeView.ItemsSource` based on the `ListBox.SelectedItem` or `ListBox.SelectedIndex`

```
<Style x:Key="EmployeeTreeStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <!-- By default bind to MyListBox.SelectedItem.Leaves -->
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Leaves}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!-- If SelectedIndex = 0, bind to AllLeaves instead -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding AllLeaves}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Update based on comments below**

```
<Style x:Key="EmployeeTreeStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!-- Set ItemsSource based on which RadioButton is Selected -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=RadioButton1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding AllLeaves}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=RadioButton2, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ElementName=RadioButton2, Path=DataContext.Leaves}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I'm not actually using a ListBox. I'm using RadioButtons. Does this idea work for RadioButtons too?

Comment: you definitly mean SelectedIndex Value=-1, not =0. 0 is the first entry selected, -1 is no entry is selected...

Comment: @KendallFrey Yes, the same concept would apply to `RadioButtons`.

Comment: How could I get it to work with RadioButtons? Using a DataTrigger to check for a checked RadioButton?

Comment: @eFloh I'm assuming the first entry is "All Items" and the starting `SelectedIndex` is set to 0, since it sounds like the user should be allowed to navigate back to the All Items selection.

Comment: @KendallFrey Yes, you'd have your DataTrigger check the `MyRadioButton.Checked` property with a binding, and if it's `True` set the `ItemsSource` to whatever you want. I can update the example if you want.

Comment: @KendallFrey Ok, it's been updated. You'll probably have to mess with the bindings a bit depending on how your application is setup, but it should give the general idea

Comment: @Rachel: good point, I missed that... For the point of good UI design, I would recommend using ( ) All Items (o) Only selected: followed by a list that is disabled when all items is choosen.

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure what your asking... but I'll give it ago.

if your set the DataContext to something like this;

```
 public class PresentationModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object _userPropertyA;
    public object UserPropertyA
    {
        get { return _userPropertyA; }
        set
        {
            _userPropertyA = value;

            //Set the data source based on the value of the selected?
            DataSource = new List<object>();
        }
    }

    private object _userPropertyB;
    public object UserPropertyB
    {
        get { return _userPropertyB; }
        set
        {
            _userPropertyB = value;

            //Set the data source based on the value of the selected?
            DataSource = new List<object>();
        }
    }

    public List<object> DataSource { get; set; }

    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

and then bind the properties to the required controls

this would allow you to change your datasource based on the values passed by the user.

ofcourse you will need to also implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Does that help?

cheers.
ste.

Comment: for the INotifyPropertyChanged to work, you have to call `OnPropertyChanged("DataSource")` after `DataSource = new List<object>();`